# Like and = operater is not working together in signal query

Tags: sql, asp.net, search

I am using sap.net web form. In this web form i have a text and a button. user enter name or id and hit search button. Searching with id is working fine but with name it is not working.
What i am missing here help me out please.

```
  String Status = "Active";
        String BDstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(BDstring))
        {
            try
            {
                String query = "SELECT * from Driver where(Name LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR DriverID = @search) AND Status = 'Active'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", SearchTextBox.Text);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader SDR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                if (SDR.HasRows)
                {
                    DT.Load(SDR);
                    GridView.DataSource = DT;
                    GridView.DataBind();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException exe)
            {
                throw exe;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: Because i tested it.

Comment: And **what happened**? Do you get an exception thrown, perhaps complaining about not being able to convert a varchar to an int?

Comment: when i use LIKE every where than its work fine also

Comment: No exception is thrown

Comment: I'm almost certain an exception is being thrown - do you have any empty `catch` blocks higher up the call stack?

Comment: there is no exception thrown its just not showing any output

Comment: String query = "SELECT * from Driver where(Name LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR DriverID LIKE '%' + @search+'%') AND Status = 'Active'"; when i use this one its works fine

Comment: What's the data type of the `DriverID` column?

Comment: data type is integer

Comment: it is generally a bad idea to use 1 search string on different columns of different types, either add a new parameter `@ID` of type iint and use that on the ID field or convert the `DriverID` to a varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is generating an exception. The fact that you're unaware of this indicates that you have "error handling" somewhere in your system that is, in fact "error hiding". Remove empty `catch` blocks, or pointless `catch` blocks such as the one in your question that just destroys some information in the exception and re-throws it. Those aren't helping you.

The actual problem is that the `DriverID` column is `int` and your parameter is `varchar`. So long as the `varchar` contains a string that can be converted to a number (which is the direction that the conversion happens in due to [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql)), the query is well-formed.

As soon as the parameter contains a string that cannot be implicitly converted to a number, SQL Server generates an error that .NET turns into an exception.

For your `LIKE` variant, you're forcing a conversion in the opposite direction (numeric -> varchar) since `LIKE` only operates on strings. That conversion will always succeed, but it means that you're performing textual comparisons rather than numeric, and also means there's no possible index usage here.

I'd suggest that you change your C# code to attempt a `int.TryParse` on the input text and then uses *two* separate parameters to pass strings and (optionally) their numeric equivalent to SQL Server. Then use the appropriate parameters in your query for each comparison.

---

Something like:

```
String Status = "Active";
String BDstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(BDstring))
{
    String query = "SELECT * from Driver where(Name LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR " +
                   "DriverID = @driverId) AND Status = 'Active'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = SearchTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@driverId", SqlDbType.Int);
    int driverId;
    if(int.TryParse(SearchTextBox.Text, out driverId))
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@driverId"].Value = driverId;
    }
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader SDR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    if (SDR.HasRows)
    {
        DT.Load(SDR);
        GridView.DataSource = DT;
        GridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: i convert the Driver id to int now its throwing an error that string i not in correct format

Comment: @fahad - I've attempted to update the example code, but obviously can't compile and debug it myself given that its incomplete. Not sure what you've changed, but be very clear on *what data types* are involved everywhere and *make sure the types match* - try to prevent any implicit conversions from happening. Once you get to that point, you shouldn't be getting any conversion errors. Your comment is unclear since Driver id was already `int`.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT * from Driver where (Name LIKE '%" + @search + "%'
OR DriverID = '" + @search + "' ) AND Status = 'Active'";

how about this?

Comment: no its says name search does not exist in this context

Comment: you have moved the SQL variable outside of the query string so it wont compile

Comment: This would appear to be *adding* an SQL Injection vulnerability to code which did not previously have one. Not really recommended.

Comment: before sending a query, I think can defend from the SQL Injection by inputing text validation.